# Show an element right after one that has been clicked

Tags: javascript, html, toggle, hide

When I click a `section`, how to toggle another `div`?

Here is my code:

```
<body>
<div id="div1" onClick="toggle_visibility('div2')">
    <section id="0" value="0" > room 101 </section>
    <section id="1" value="0"> room 102</section>
    <section id="2" value="0"> room 103 </section>
    <section id="3" value="0"> room 104 </section>
    <section id="4" value="0"> room 105 </section>
</div>

<div id="div2" style="display:none">
    <section id="0" value="0"> item1 </section>
    <section id="1" value="0"> item2 </section>
    <section id="2" value="0"> item3 </section>
    <section id="3" value="0"> item4 </section>
    <section id="4" value="0"> item5 </section>
</div>

<script>
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if(e.style.display == 'block')
        e.style.display == 'none';
    else
        e.style.display = 'block';
}
</script>
</body>
```

I want the output like this: when I click any room, the all five items will be toggled and shown just beneath the room.

For example: When I click room 101, the outcome should looks like this:

```
room 101
item1
item2
item3
item4
item5
room 102
room 103
room 104
room 105
```

Comment: You should be using an interactive element like a `button` or an `a` instead of a div. If you insist on using a `div` you need to add `role="button"`, `tabindex`, `onkeydown`, etc to make it accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The snippet below will do it.

It gets the `section` that's clicked by using [event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.target).

It moves `div2` to that `section` by using [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild).

It also corrects an error in your code.  This:

```
e.style.display == 'none';
```

… should be:

```
e.style.display = 'none';
```

**Code:**

```js
function toggle_visibility(event) {
  var e = document.getElementById('div2');
  event.target.appendChild(e);
  
  if(e.style.display === 'block') {
    e.style.display = 'none';
  }
  else {
    e.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" onClick="toggle_visibility(event)">
  <section id="0" value="0"> room 101 </section>
  <section id="1" value="0"> room 102 </section>
  <section id="2" value="0"> room 103 </section>
  <section id="3" value="0"> room 104 </section>
  <section id="4" value="0"> room 105 </section>
</div>

<div id="div2" style="display:none">
  <section id="0" value="0"> item1 </section>
  <section id="1" value="0"> item2 </section>
  <section id="2" value="0"> item3 </section>
  <section id="3" value="0"> item4 </section>
  <section id="4" value="0"> item5 </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I use jquery detach/appendTo mecahnism. I put a hidden  div in the html and when I do this:

```
$('#element').detach().appendTo('#hiddendiv')
```

then when I want to put it back I just invert the process with #element's parent as destination.

Comment: See the tags, jQuery is not there. that's should be a solution. I think that the OP needs is pure JS :/

Answer (score 0):

This should work, on click on section in div1, toggle every section in div2, detach them and append them after the current section which was clicked:

```
$('#div1 section').click(function () {
   var det =  $("#div2 section").toggle().detach();
   $(this).after(det); 
});
```

Comment: See the tags, jQuery is not there. that's should be a solution. I think that the OP needs is pure JS :/